# How to create a ResourceBundle and fill it with keys and values

Tags: java, bundle

I have a list of keys/values stored in a database, and i want to create a new `ResourceBundle` and fill it with these keys/values, what is the best way to do this, i tried to create a new instance of `ListResourceBundle`, and i want to know if this solution is the right one :

```
ListResourceBundle MyClassBundle = new ListResourceBundle() {

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return contents; 
    }

    private Object[][] contents = {
        {"code", "Code"},
        {"name", "Name"},};            
};
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [JavaDoc of that clas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListResourceBundle.html) you have to extends it and then implement initialization as you wish: from property file or any another source.